# Image change event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a mx:Image Component and I am changing the picture with this code:

```
image.source = "path_to_picture";
```

This works fine. Now I would like to know, when the picture is loaded, so I registered a COMPLETE-Event

```
image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

but I does not fire. Is there another Event I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a state issue. The image control was not in a visible state when I triggered the image change, so no event has been fired.
Damn you, flex ;P

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the complete event has already fired before you added the listener. If the path is on your local disk, then it could load very fast. You can check if it's loaded by tracing `image.percentLoaded` at the point when the listener is added.

Comment: I am addind the listender on component initialization, so I don't think this is the problem.